# Sources for Auto-Complete

Tags: init-file, package, package-repositories, auto-complete-mode, config

I still feel a strong disturbance when it comes to `auto-complete` in `emacs`.
From what I have read in the [docs](http://auto-complete.org/doc/manual.html), you can easily extend `auto-complete` by any syntax you like. Looking through (M)ELPA there are many packages named `ac-[...]`, like `ac-html-bootstrap`.

After installing some of these packages, I am not sure if there is any difference, since `auto-complete` already shifts with various syntax.

General Question:
What is the general *cookbook recipe* for installing **3rd party** syntax packages for `auto-compete`?

In more details:
**(i)** How does `auto-complete` get notified about 3rd party syntax packages in general? Does it scan the directory or do I need to specify it in my `.emacs` file?
**(ii)** How is it hooked to a certain mode or file extension? Is this provided by the syntax package itself or do I have to specify it?
**(iii)** How do I make sure, a package is correctly working? How do I tell the difference between the state without and with the package?

Comment: I don't use auto-complete so I can't speak to the majority of your questions but when installing something from melpa I always find that  opening the readme from github is essential for proper installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/444) and received a nice answer by [syohex](https://github.com/syohex):

> > (i) How does auto-complete get notified about 3rd party syntax packages in general? Does it scan the directory or do I need to specify it in my .emacs file?
>
> Load 3rd party package in your configuration file. For example,
>
> `(require 'ac-html-bootstrap)`
>
> > (ii) How is it hooked to a certain mode or file extension? Is this provided by the syntax package itself or do I have to specify it?
>
> Add 3rd party source to ac-sources in specific mode hook(eg, python-mode-hook, ruby-mode-hook, etc). For example,
>
> `(require 'ac-c-headers)
>   (defun my/c-mode-hook ()
>     (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers))
>   (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my/c-mode-hook)`
>
> `ac-sources` is a buffer local variable so above configuration does not affect other major-mode buffers.
>
> > (iii) How do I make sure, a package is correctly working? How do I tell the difference between the state without and with the package?
>
> You can get expected candidates then it looks working correctly. For example if you use go-autocomplete, then you should get candidates of Go methods, variable names, functions.